How to create combinations from dataframes for a specific combination size
Say I have a dataframe with 2 columns, how would I create all possible combinations for a specific combination size? Each row of the df should be treated as 1 item in the combination rather than 2 unique separate items. I want the columns of the combinations to be appended to the right. The solution should ideally be efficient since it takes long to generate all the combinations with a large list.
For example, I want to create all possible combinations with a combination size of 3.
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['a','b','c','d'], 'B':['1','2','3','4']})

How would I get my dataframe to look like this?
    A  B  A  B  A  B
0   a  1  b  2  c  3
1   a  1  b  2  d  4
2   a  1  c  3  d  4
3   b  2  c  3  d  4


An approach is itertools to generate the combinations.

Define the combination size and generate all possible combinations of rows using itertools.combinations
Flatten each combination into a single list of values using itertools.chain.
combination_df is created from the flattened combinations and the columns are dynamically generated to repeat 'A' and 'B' for each combination

Sample
import itertools
combination_size = 3
combinations = list(itertools.combinations(df.values, combination_size))
combination_df = pd.DataFrame(
    [list(itertools.chain(*comb)) for comb in combinations],
    columns=[col for i in range(combination_size) for col in df.columns]
)
    )

EDIT : Optimisation as suggested by @ouroboros1
combination_df = pd.DataFrame( (chain.from_iterable(c) for c in combinations), columns=np.tile(df.columns, combination_size) )

Output
   A  B  A  B  A  B
0  a  1  b  2  c  3
1  a  1  b  2  d  4
2  a  1  c  3  d  4
3  b  2  c  3  d  4


Nice. I think you can optimize that slightly, using chain.from_iterable and then np.tile for the column labels: pd.DataFrame((chain.from_iterable(c) for c in combinations(df.values, combination_size)), columns=np.tile(df.columns, combination_size)) (with from itertools import combinations, chain)

@ouroboros1 I get a TypeError: 'list' object is not callable error when I use combination_df = pd.DataFrame((chain.from_iterable(c) for c in combinations(df.values, combination_size)), columns=np.tile(df.columns, combination_size))

@blahahaaahahaa: see e.g. this post. You will have overwritten the built-in functionality of list, doing something like list = [1,2,3]. Don't use list as a variable name. Afterwards, something like list((1,2,3)) no longer works as it should. Try del list or restart your kernel and get rid of any such line. Incidentially, seems unlikely that you are gettting this error on this bit of code, but never mind that. You need to restore the built-in function.

Thanks @ouroboros1 for the suggestion!

I have EDITed the answer with the optimisation suggestion and checked it returns the expected result, @blahahaaahahaa let us know if you still facing issue.
